# Updating a thread local value (concurrency C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, thread-local

I'am learning concurrency in C++ and I want to know how can I update a threadlocal storage value ? Here is a simple example

```
struct ThreadPool
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::atomic_bool done;
    static thread_local std::unique_ptr<int> valueLocal;
    const uint8_t nbThread = 1; //Just for example

    ThreadPool()
    {
        done = false;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < nbThread; ++i)
        {
            threads.push_back(
                std::thread(&ThreadPool::WorkerThread, this));
        }
    }

    void WorkerThread()
    {
        while (!done)
        {
            std::cout << "WorkerThread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " : " << valueLocal <<std::endl;
        }
    }

    void UpdateValue(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "Update value " << std::this_thread::get_id()  << " : "  << valueLocal << std::endl;
        valueLocal ++;
    }
};

thread_local std::unique_ptr<int> ThreadPool::valueLocal = std::make_unique<int>(100);
```

I try to create a thread pool which have a local value storage of 100, then I try  to update this value on the UpdateValue function

But because the adress of localValue on the function UpdateValue and the one on the thread are not the same, I cannot update the value on a specific thread. So how can I go the thread to update the value ?

The  next idea is to give each thread of the thread pool, his owns vector of data for use function but for now I try an simple example

Thanks a lot !

Edit to answer the answer

Thanks for you for you answer

@Scheff indeed their is an issue.. but the compiler didn't raise and error

@besmirched : In fact i'am reading the book "Concurrency in action in C++" on the chapter of "Thread Pool"

On each the author create an "thread local queue" for each threads, but then after when he tries to submit function, he did the same thing as me..

So he can "update the value" of a thread local variable on a thread. So he make a big mistake or I don't undestand his logic..

I don't know if I can copy his code here....

Comment: Something is wrong with your exposed code: With `valueLocal` of type `std::unique_ptr<int>`, neither the `std::cout << valueLocal` nor the `valueLocal++` should be compiled without any complaint. Are you sure you copied your last successfully compiled example? (At least, I couldn't convince g++ 9.2 to compile this: [test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/465452ab26d04617).)

Comment: `thread_local` is only meant for data that are _not_ shared between threads. The main use-case for it is when you're trying to bring old, single-threaded code into a multi-threaded program. Anywhere the old code uses a global variable, `thread_local` is an easy way to give each thread its own private copy.

Comment: Thanks for you for you answer